# A sequence of sets increasing to a limit $A$

Tags: measure-theory

Terminology and definition question:

When we say

> A sequence of sets $A_1,A_2,...$ belong to a field $\mathscr{F}$ and increases to a limit $A$.

Does this equivalently mean

> $A_1\subset A_2\subset ...$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=A$

What I am confused is that when someone says "a sequence of sets increase to a limit A", do we assume it is an increase sequence of sets converging to a set in the limit? Is it possible to state a sequence of sets increase to a limit A without presupposing the sequence is an increasing sequence?

Reference:
$\textit{Probability and Measure Theory}$ (Robert B. Ash and Catherine A. Doleans-Dade), Harcourt/Academic Press, 1999.

Comment: Yes, it should mean that you have containment $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$ and that the union is $A$. A sequence of sets can only really be said to "increase" when you are adding in new elements at each stage. Conversely, you could say a sequence $B_n$ *decreases* to a limit $B$ if $B_1 \supseteq B_2 \supseteq \cdots$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n = B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

There is a concept of limit of a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of sets, which is as follows: a set $A$ is the limit of such a sequence if $A$ satisfies both conditions:

1. $A=\{x\in\mathscr F\mid x\in A_n\text{ for infinitely many $n$'s}\}$:
2. $A=\{x\in\mathscr F\mid(\exists N\in\mathbb N)(\forall n\in\mathbb N):n\geqslant N\implies x\in A_n\}$.

But if the sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing and if you take $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}$, then both of those conditions hold and therefore you have $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ indeed.

Note that if the if the sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing and if you take $A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}$, then both conditions hold too and therefore you have $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ ind this case too.

There are cases in which the limit exists but the $A_n$'s are not nested. Take, for instance, $\mathscr F=\mathbb Q$ and, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $A_n=\{0,n\}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\{0\}$.

Comment: Are there cases where 1,2 hold but the sets are not nested? My guess is yes, and if so such an example would be good to include in your answer.

Comment: Done. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for that example, Jose. (sorry, didn't know how to put accent on e.)